# could not find library.dll in modelica

Tags: dll, fortran, modelica, dynamic-links

I wrote a Fortran code and make it TestDLL.dll and TestDLL.lib file. I want use that in OpenModelica. But the Modelica say that

> could not find library TestDLL in either of:~~~

I put .dll and .lib file in `E:\MODELICAEXAM` (my modelica work space) or `E:\MODELICAEXAM\MyPackage\Resouces`, but it doesn't work.

I read the ModelicaSpec34 document(12.9.4) which describe about "annotation", but I really confuse about what is "modelica://".

So I have two question about that:

1. can I use fortran dll in the modelica?
2. If first question is ok, where should I put my lib and dll file to make modelica find these files? or I misunderstood the question?

The code as below

```
function SUB(a,b)
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::SUB
    implicit none
    real :: a,b
    real :: SUB
    SUB = a+b
return
end
```

modelica part

```
model test
    function sub
       input Real a;
       input Real b;
       output Real Result;
       external "C" Result = sub(a, b);
       annotation(
       Library = "TestDLL",
       LibraryDirectory = 
           "modelica://MyPackage/Resouces");
    end sub;

    Real result;
    parameter Real a = 1;
    parameter Real b = 2;
equation
    result = sub(a, b);
end test;!
```

Comment: What does the spec says about annotation? What you tried is not Fortran, it can't compile. How did you make the dll? Did you get any error message?

Comment: the spec says that the annotation(LibraryDirectory="modelica://LibraryName/Resources/Library"),  but I don't know what does the "modelica://"represent. The Fortran code that I have compiled  in IVF 2013  have already been tried in another Fortran code and works well.

Comment: this is the modelicaspec34 document https://www.modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec34.pdf

Comment: OpenModelica uses GCC so you need to compile your code to a libTestDLL.a or .dll using gfortran. Extension .lib does not work.

Comment: Can't you quote from the document yourself so that all other people don't have to? You are asking for help, after all.

Comment: The `LibraryDirectory` specification looks nothing like what would work on Windows. Maybe this is converted by OpenModelica into something else. I will comment, though, that the error "could not find library DLL" often means that a DLL that your DLL depends on could not be found. This happens most often when you build a debug-configuration DLL that depends on C++ (and possibly Fortran) support DLLs that are available only when inside Visual Studio or a compiler build environment. Which compiler are you using and how did you build the DLL?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.  I have solved this question.  Fortran make the variable to capital form automatically.  When I use this function in modelica, I must use capital  form to call the function.  The "modelica://" means the file folder where the. mo file located.